# IE 7 acting strange or is it just me

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have a html like this: The idea is that divs are floated left and when there are more than 3 divs. The next one shoud start at the next line. (Because of the width). This works in almost all the browsers. Even in IE6. But when it comes to IE7. It puts the 4th div on the same line.
Any ideas why?

```
<div id="content">
    <div>
        <div class="picture" style="float: left; margin-right: 8px;">
            <div class="pictureName">Name...</div><a href="#" class="borderfree"><img alt="" src="/xsmall.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="picture" style="float: left; margin-right: 8px;">
            <div class="pictureName">Name...</div><a href="#" class="borderfree"><img alt="" src="/xsmall.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="picture" style="float: left; margin-right: 8px;">
            <div class="pictureName">Name...</div><a href="#" class="borderfree"><img alt="" src="/xsmall.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="picture" style="float: left; margin-right: 8px;">
            <div class="pictureName">Name...</div><a href="#" class="borderfree"><img alt="" src="/xsmall.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="picture" style="float: left; margin-right: 8px;">
            <div class="pictureName">Name...</div><a href="#" class="borderfree"><img alt="" src="/xsmall.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
#content {
margin:10px auto;
overflow:hidden;
padding:3px 10px;
}
```

Here are some pictures:
Any ideas why?
IE7
[IE7 http://www.suaygiri.com/temp/ie7.jpg](http://www.suaygiri.com/temp/ie7.jpg)

IE8
[IE8 The Correct One http://www.suaygiri.com/temp/ie8.jpg](http://www.suaygiri.com/temp/ie8.jpg)

Comment: What happens when you add "width: 100%" to the "#content" style? (Well actually you can't really do that with the w3c standards-mode box model; the point is, what if you fix the width?)

Comment: Why the extra `<div>` inside content?

Comment: I changed the witdh for the div below #content (which contains the pictures divs) it did not have ay effect.

@Hogan I thought it would be a better idea to set the witdh of that inner <div> so U wouldnt have the change #content's properties as it is shared in other pages.

Comment: I see that -- you don't show the code for that in your example here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try position:relative and display:inline; to .picture
also all the containers have to have fixed widths

if that doesn't work then you have something else going on

```
#content {
margin:10px auto;
overflow:hidden;
padding:3px 10px;
width:960px;

}
.picture{
float:left;
width:320px;
position:relative;
display:inline;
}
```

edit:  I didn't notice the extra div....  shouldn't cause a problem though.

Comment: Well I guess giving it a witdh property does the work. However I'm doing some more testing and will let you if anything changes. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Looked at your page -- this may or may not be the problem, but I notice you don't have a legal DOCTYPE.  Try fixing that first.

My bad -- I was looking at the Chrome inspector not the source.  The DOCTYPE looks fine.

Comment: the actual page, located http://www.ponentebaby.com/kategori has the correct doctype. At least I think so cause the w3 validator doesnt complain

Comment: that rule would make all divs inside content to be 960px ... you should use the > child selector `#content > div {...}`. Keep in mind that it is not supported in IE 6..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove the `overflow:hidden;` property?

I've tried in Safari, and removing the `overflow:hidden;` does not seem to change the layout

( don't have IE7 here so I can't really test it )

Comment: overflow:hidden should have nothing to do with what he is asking I think

Comment: I don't have IE7 all the time. But I found something called Microsoft Expression Web SuperPreview for Windows Internet Explorer which lets you browse pages with IE6, IE7 and IE8 and make comparisons etc. here's the link: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8e6ac106-525d-45d0-84db-dccff3fae677&displaylang=en